# c++ convert time returned by NTP server to string

Tags: c++

i'm new in c++, and want to convert an epoch value from NTP server to a human readable date time value.

```
void printTime() {
  /*
  Human time (GMT): Friday, May 17, 2019 8:44:16 AM
  Human time (your time zone): Friday, May 17, 2019 10:44:16 AM GMT+02:00
  */
  unsigned long e = 1558082656;
  time_t epoch = e;
  struct tm *timeinfo_e;
  char buf[80];

  time(&epoch);
  timeinfo_e = gmtime(&epoch);
  std::cout << "epoch: " << asctime(timeinfo_e) << std::endl;
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", timeinfo_e);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

but it shows the current time, not the time of that epoch value.
what is the problem?

thanks!

Comment: By epoch value, do you mean the time returned by the NTP server? The vast majority of uses of the word "epoch" in software refer to the beginning of 1970, so your question comes across as a little confusing.

Comment: edited the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time(&epoch);
```

This stores the current time into `epoch`, overwriting the value you previously assigned. If you take that out, your program will display the UNIX time you assigned to `epoch`.

However, C++ comes with its own datetime library, and it's scheduled to be [vastly improved come C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), where it should be able to avoid the C API completely. As of today, you can already see what I'd call an improvement to understanding the code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace chr = std::chrono;

void printTime() {
  using Clock = chr::system_clock;
  unsigned long e = 1558082656;

  chr::time_point<Clock> time(chr::seconds{e});
  auto c_time = Clock::to_time_t(time); // Gone if using C++20's to_stream function
  std::cout << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&c_time), "%c %Z"); // localtime for the user's timezone
}
```

If you feel that it's currently a bit roundabout going to `time_point` and back, despite the explicit indication of seconds since the clock's epoch, then [`put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) is still of use as a more convenient way to print C times.